# Detecting when Mongod's port is open inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb

I'm trying to write a bash script that starts a `mongod` process, waits for it to start (i.e. have it's default port open) and then pipe some commands into it through the `mongo` shell. I'd like some way to wait for the mongod process to be completely up that's more deterministic than just `sleep 5`.

This is the script so far:

```
set_up_authorization() {
    echo "Setting up access control"
    /path/to/mongo < configure_access_controls.js
}

wait_for_mongod_to_start() {
    RETRIES=1000
    CONNECTED="false"
    echo "Waiting for mongod to start"
    while [[ $RETRIES -ge 0 && $CONNECTED == "false" ]] ; do
        RESPONSE=$(exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/27017 || echo "1")
        if [[ $RESPONSE == "" ]] # which should happen if the exec is successful
            CONNECTED="true"
        fi
        RETRIES=$((RETRIES - 1))
    done
    if [[ $RETRIES -eq 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Max retries reached waiting for mongod to start. Exiting."
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Mongod started"
}

./start_mongod_instance.sh
wait_for_mongod_to_start
set_up_authorization
```

While this script works, it produces a ton of output on the terminal while the exec is failing:

```
./initialize_cluster.sh: connect: Connection refused
./initialize_cluster.sh: line xx: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/27017: Connection refused
```

...which repeats for all ~900 failed attempts.

Neither of the following seems to get rid of the terminal logging either:

```
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/27017 >/dev/null
OR
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/27017 2>/dev/null
```

I've also tried using the following:

```
ps -aux | grep "mongod" | wc -l
```

but the process having a pid that ps lists isn't equivalent to it's port being open or it accepting connections.

Any ideas on either front would be appreciated - a more elegant way to wait for the process to start completely or a way to get rid of the excessive logging to the terminal.

Note: I don't have access to `nmap` or `nc` to check the port (this is on a client's machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` is a bit special. It affects the output of the *current* shell. Meaning you need to redirect stderr of the current shell before running the port check:

```
host="localhost"
port="9000"
exec 2>/dev/null # redirect error here
while ! exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/${host}/${port}" ; do
    echo "Waiting ..."
    sleep 1
done
```

Furthermore you might have noticed that I check the exit status of `exec` rather than some output to decide whether the port is open or not.

---

If you want to reset it afterwards:

```
host="localhost"
port="9000"

# Copy fd 2 into fd 3 and redirect fd 2 to /dev/null
exec 3<&2 2>/dev/null

while ! exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/${host}/${port}" ; do
    echo "Waiting ..."
    sleep 1
done

# Copy back fd 3 into fd 2
exec 2<&3
echo "EE oops!" >&2
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, using `/dev/tcp` is imo a very elegant method to achieve you goal!